# Approximating $\sin(x)$ on $[−1, 1]$ in $L^2$ with a second degree polynomial

Tags: approximation-theory, legendre-polynomials

$p_n : [−1, 1] →
\mathbb{R} (n \in \mathbb{N})$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

$p_n$ is an orthonormal system, $\int_{-1}^{1}p_n(x)p_m(x)dx=\delta_{m,n}$.

---

The first task was to calculate $p_0, p_1$ and $p_2$. I did that with the Gram-Schmidt process, I got $p_o(x)=1, p_1(x)=x$ and $p_2(x)=\dfrac 32(x^2-\dfrac 13)$.

---

The second task is this: Which second degree polynomial approximates $\sin(x)$ on $[−1, 1]$ in $L^2$ the best?

Hint: $\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-s_N(x)|^2dx$ and $||f||_2= \sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^2dx}$

I have no idea what to do, can someone help me?

Comment: You want the projection of $\sin$ on the subspace spanned by $p_0$, $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: The general formula for the best approximation is $ \langle f, p_1 \rangle p_1+\langle f, p_2 \rangle p_2+\langle f, p_3 \rangle p_3$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p_0, p_1, p_2$ are three orthonormal polynomials of degree $\leq 2$. Then the best $L^2$ approximation of any function $f$ on $[-1,1]$ in $span\{p_0, p_1, p_2\}$ is $g(x) = a_0p_0(x)+a_1p_1(x)+a_2p_2(x)$ where $a_i = \int_{-1}^1 p_i(x)f(x)dx$.

Comment: In particular, since $\sin(x)$ is odd, $a_0=a_2=0.$

Comment: I got $a_1 = \int_{-1}^1 x\sin(x)dx=-2\cos(1)+2\sin(1)$. Then would $g(x)=(-2\cos(1)+2\sin(1))x$ follow. Approximating a function with the function itself seems wrong and this also doesn't look like a second degree polynomial. So I'm pretty sure that I understood wrong but I don't know what. I also got $a_0=a_2=0$.

Comment: No because $x$ is not normalized, you will need to divide your $a_1$ by $\int_{-1}^1 x^2 dx$ to get the correct coefficient

Comment: Ohh yes I forgot that, but then it's still $g(x)=\dfrac{(-2\cos(1)+2\sin(1))3x}  {2}$. Can I really approximate a function with the same function? That doesn't seem satisfying to me

Comment: What do you mean by "approximate a function with the same function"

Comment: Well, we had to approximate $\sin(x)$ and we use $\sin$ in our solution. I don't really see the point of approximating then, the only good thing now is that it's a polynomial. Is that just good enough? I feel like a more satisfying result would've been something without trigonometric functions

Comment: But $\sin(x)$ is a function, while $\cos(1)$ and $\sin(1)$ are real numbers. Us being able to calculate them is a different question. The question is just to find the best approximation, not to be able to calculate it